# skimage.morphology.watershed causes 32 Bit Kernel to die

Tags: python, memory, 32-bit, scikit-image, watershed

When using Python 3.6.4 **32-Bit** with skimage version 0.13.1 the following code leads to a dieing kernel:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import skimage.morphology
import skimage.feature
import scipy
import numpy as np
import psutil
import os

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print('Mem usage %4.1f MB after imports\n'%(process.memory_info().vms / float(2 ** 20)))
data = loadmat('demoData.mat')
print('Mem usage %4.1f MB after loading the data'%(process.memory_info().vms / float(2 ** 20)))
print('Mem available: %4.1f MB\n'%(psutil.virtual_memory().available/float(2 ** 20)))

#Just show the input data
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.figure('Watershed')
#plt.clf()
#plt.imshow(data['pic'])


#%%Do some Calculations
l = 10 # hysteresis for Canny edge detector lower limit
h = 20 # hysteresis for Canny edge detector high limit
sigma = 0.1

gradient = skimage.filters.sobel(data['pic'])
# find forground and background
l,h = 10, 20 # hysteresis for Canny edge detector

cannyPic = skimage.feature.canny(data['pic'], sigma = sigma, low_threshold=l, high_threshold=h)
print('Mem usage %4.1f MB after CannyPic'%(process.memory_info().vms / float(2 ** 20)))
print('Mem available: %4.1f MB\n'%(psutil.virtual_memory().available/float(2 ** 20)))

markers = cannyPic == 0
print('Mem usage %4.1f MB after markers'%(process.memory_info().vms / float(2 ** 20)))
print('Mem available: %4.1f MB\n'%(psutil.virtual_memory().available/float(2 ** 20)))

seg = np.ones((3,3))
markers, numFeatures = scipy.ndimage.measurements.label(markers, seg)
print('Mem usage %4.1f MB after label'%(process.memory_info().vms / float(2 ** 20)))
print('Mem available: %4.1f MB\n'%(psutil.virtual_memory().available/float(2 ** 20)))

#***** Crash occurs in the line below ****
labels = skimage.morphology.watershed(gradient, markers)
print('Mem usage %4.1f MB after watershed'%(process.memory_info().vms / float(2 ** 20)))
print('Mem available: %4.1f MB\n'%(psutil.virtual_memory().available/float(2 ** 20)))
```

It works fine with the 64Bit Version and it works fine for smaller images. Therefor I guessed there might be a memory problem. But judging from the output of the earlier calls to sobel, canny, and markers the memory usage is not critically high, and there is lots of availabel memory left.
The output is as follows:

> Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (32-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:21:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
> IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>
> runfile('H:/CVS/python/171213Koexexperimente/32BitCrashWatershedExample.py', wdir='H:/CVS/python/171213Koexexperimente')
> Mem usage 180.1 MB after imports
>
> Mem usage 262.7 MB after loading the data
> Mem available: 2790.7 MB
>
> Mem usage 355.6 MB after CannyPic
> Mem available: 2723.8 MB
>
> Mem usage 365.9 MB after markers
> Mem available: 2717.2 MB
>
> Mem usage 396.8 MB after label
> Mem available: 2682.6 MB
>
>
> Kernel died, restarting

Just switching to the 64 bit version is difficult, since this code shall be used in a library called by another 32-bit software, which can not be tranfered to 64 bit easily. 
And choping the large image to smaller images and processing those wasn't entirely stable either. For different installations using 1000 by 1000 pix images worked most of the time but not necessarily if called repeatedly.

Questions:
1. How can one find the root cause of the dieing kernel?
2. Might this be a clumsy memory usage in the watershed, if it is the memory at all?
3. Does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

All hints are appreciated.

The demo data and code can be found under
http://ascona-cloud.de/index.php/s/hFaqbEkv5PUW820

Comment: Hope you an answer, but what ranges are your "pixel" values? It sounds like some sort of overflow.

Comment: In the loaded image everything is in the range from 0 to 255 (8-Bit) but is processed as np.float64.

Comment: Or, presumably np.float32 in your 32-bit system? Is it possible (or even worthwhile?) for you to convert them to the range 0-1 (and then convert back at the end so you don't get black pictures)? Sorry, I'm just looking for where your overflow is. And do you get the stack trace from the python crash?

Comment: No, it is a 64 Bit float. Adding the line data['pic'] /= data['pic'].max() did not change the result. But to be honest I'm not sure how I can get the trace from the kernel.